# Only return 1 value from SQL Server query

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I use the following query that returns the following data set.

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT (a.changelog_Histories_created) AS DateOfStatusChange,
    a.Issue_Key AS IssueKey,
    a.Changelog_Histories_author_displayName AS ChangeLogUserName,
    b.Items_fromString AS StatusChangedFrom,
    b.Items_toString AS StatusChangedTo
FROM
    [Jira].[Platform.Api_Issue_Changelog_Histories] a
    JOIN [Jira].[Platform_Items] b 
       ON a.Issue_key = b.Issue_key
       AND a.Changelog_Histories_index = b.Changelog_Histories_index
WHERE
    a.Issue_key = 'TAP-944'
    AND b.items_field = 'Status'
    AND b.Items_fromString IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    a.Issue_Key,
    a.Changelog_Histories_author_displayName,
    b.Items_fromString,
    b.Items_toString,
    b.Items_field,
    a.changelog_Histories_created
ORDER BY
    a.changelog_Histories_created DESC;
```

Data set:

[image]

I want to only see 1 status changed from and 1 status changed to distinct value.

For example looking at the screenshot, i only want to see this specific issue_key as status Open, In progress, Code review and closed not multiple times.

How does one achieve this?

Desired output

[image]

Comment: Select top 1 (or perhaps LIMIT) depending on the technology azure uses.

Comment: please show us your desired output as well

Comment: Wouldn't a top 1 with an order by do the trick. Something like the examples here: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/sql-strategies-for-versioned-data/

Comment: @eshirvana please see my desired output updated above